# I have a website running on tomcat using struts, jsp etc. While implementing PayPal using JavaScript, the paypal window is behind the browser popup

Tags: javascript, css, paypal

Here is my script.  The buttons show just as expected, but when I click on the button the Paypal login is behind the browser window.  If I close the browser window the entire PayPal process works as expected.

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=[your-client-id-here]&commit=true&currency=USD"></script>

<script>

  paypal.Buttons({
      style: {
          //style as you prefer
            shape:  "pill",
            label: "checkout"
          },

    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.order.create({
        purchase_units: [{
          amount: {
            currency_code: "USD",
            value: "${paypal.total}",
            breakdown: {
                item_total: {
                    currency_code: "USD",
                    value: "${paypal.amount}"
                },
                handling: {
                    currency_code: "USD",
                    value: "${paypal.fee}"
                }
            }
          }
        }],

        application_context: {
           shipping_preference: 'NO_SHIPPING'
        }
      });
    },

    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
            console.log(details);
            console.log(details.id);
            console.log(details.status);
            console.log(details.purchase_units[0].amount.value);
            document.location.href = "/confirmation.action?payPalOrderStatus=" + details.status + "&payPalOrderId=" + details.id + "&payPalOrderPayment=" + details.purchase_units[0].amount.breakdown.item_total.value
        });
    },

    onCancel: function(data) {
        alert("Payment Canceled");
    },

  }).render('#paypal-button-container');

</script>

<div id="paypal-button-container" ></div>
```

Here is the result:

[PayPal behind browser popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAnYz.png)

I've tried changing the script many times but nothing seems to work?  Is it possible it's a PayPal bug?  Do I need to add CSS maybe?

I've reduced the script to:

```js
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=MY ID"></script>

<div id="paypal-button-container" ></div>
<script>

  paypal.Buttons({
      style: {
          //style as you prefer
            shape:  "pill",
            label: "checkout"
          },

  }).render('#paypal-button-container');

</script>
```

[Same result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tY9kb.png)

Comment: actions.order.create / actions.order.capture are deprecated , and do not use `alert()` within the callback functions. But as for your actual issue I don't know what's causing it, perhaps your page have script polyfills that interfere with normal browser functionality. As a test, try the simplest example possible on a new page and remove everything else. Keep paring down if needed, removing HTTP headers etc